# And not to acknowledge that is becoming increasingly perverse

Tags: word-usage

Sam Harris: ...we have made tremendous progress. I mean, there is in fact less racism and sexism, and transphobia at this moment in America, and in particular in our institutions than there has ever been anywhere on Earth. **And not to acknowledge *that* is becoming increasingly perverse**.

Source: [Making Sense podcast #253 by Sam Harris](https://twitter.com/SamHarrisOrg/status/1405626320202043396)

Does "that" refer back to "racism and sexism, and transphobia"?

Comment: Harris seems to enjoy shocking people. That last sentence seems to deliberately be difficult to read, and the word "perverse" isn't what a normal person would use there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, ***that*** refers to ***the fact that*** *there is less racism and sexism, and transphobia at this moment in America, and in particular in our institutions than there has ever been anywhere on Earth.*

Sam Harris wants to point out that it is not good to ignore this achievement.

***That*** here is a pronoun and [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/that) says:

> We also use that to refer back to a whole clause:
>
> A: We’re having a few friends round for dinner. Would you like to
> come?
>
> B: ***That*** sounds lovely. (***that*** = *the fact that you're inviting me*)
>
> Why don’t you come at around 8? ***That***’ll give me time to get ready. (***that*** = *your coming at around 8*)
>
> A: Can you tell Kat to hurry up? We’ve got to leave at 11.
>
> B: I’ve already told her ***that***. (***that*** = *to hurry up*)

I have put between parentheses what ***that*** refers back to.

Comment: Nit-pick: Cambridge gives those examples but *doesn't* offer exactly what **that** refers to except 'the whole clause'. In the first example IMO **that** refers to "coming round to dinner" and in the second one, **that** could be either "told her to hurry" or "told her we leave at 11".

Comment: Certainly *that* could refer to the whole clause.  But it could more simply refer to just the single word "progress", with the whole "I mean" clause defining what the writer means by "progress".

Comment: @WeatherVane: Yes you are right to split hairs for the sake of clarity. In fact, in the second example, **that** could refer to both "told her to hurry" and "told her we leave at 11".

Comment: @Kirt Yes, very correct. The "I mean" clause could be considered a sort of "apposition" of the word progress. In fact, I don't think it's wrong to consider that this **that** includes both "progress" and the explanation of that progress.

Comment: The best antecedant for "that" is probably the first sentence "we have made tremendous progress". Before we can say "and you have to acknowledge that" we need to explain what sort of progress it is.